# how to Print results from random.sample as the index value with its corresponding location in the index?

Tags: python, random

new to python here. the output of this code is somewhat correct but only when quarters is 3. I am having trouble writing this code to print correctly for any amount of quarters or players.

### my main issue is if nquarters is changed then the code will not "assign" all the available quarters to the randomly selected "players"

current output:
player 3 has quarter 1
player 1 has quarter 2
player 2 has quarter 3
[3, 1, 2]

output when players =10 and nquarters= 4 :
player 6 has quarter 1
player 5 has quarter 2
player 1 has quarter 4
[6, 7, 5, 1]

it should also say thar player 7 has quarter 2 and instead say player 5 has quarter 3 not quarter 2

also to prevent issues later, if I need to update where the quarter location is, should I instead be using a dictionary?

I plan to eventually use this code to simulate the probability of a player "sending" a quarter to another player, and if a player has too many quarters, end the simulation and print out the player and quarter number.

```
import random

def check_qnumber():
    flag = False
    nplayer = 4
    nquarter = 3

    n = (nquarter - 2)
    run_time = n - 1
    my_list = random.sample(range(nplayer), nquarter)
    quarter_num1 = my_list[n]
    quarter_n = my_list[n]
    # search for the quarter
    quarter1 = my_list.index(quarter_num1) - n+1
    quarter2 = quarter1 + 1
    quarter3 = quarter2 + n


    print('player', my_list[n-(nquarter+n)], 'has quarter', quarter1)
    print('player', my_list[n], 'has quarter', quarter2)

    if not flag:
        if run_time == nquarter:
            flag = True
            print(my_list)
            return

    if run_time != nquarter:
        run_time -= 1
        print('player', my_list[n + 1], 'has quarter', quarter3)
        print(my_list)


check_qnumber()
```

Comment: looks like a good attempt at code. if you could post the expected outcome this would be most helpful...

Comment: @D.L Currently the outcome for the code as-is is what I want to see. however if you change Nquarter then it will not print all different combinations of which player has which quarter correctly. I think a dictionary might be a better way to do this, but my main problem is getting the code to "assign" all the available quarters to randomly selected players.

Comment: i am not sure that i follow the logic of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @D.L gothcya. this is just one part of a project. I am trying to make a function that creates a list of a specific length. this length being "the number of quarters". in that same list, the values are ''players'' picked at random. From there I need to track which player has which quarter. knowing that will be important later as I plan on simulating the quarters the quarters moving to different players. Sorry for the confusion, I am not entire sure if this is the best way to go about performing this task